# How can I fix my configuration so Vitest + Happy-Dom + RTL renders class names

Tags: css, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm in the process of migrating our test runner from jest to vitest, and am having a bit of an issue related to the output of class names during tests. Currently, the class names are not being rendered at all during tests. It works as expected running the package proper in a browser, and I'm unsure of what I'm missing to get it working.

vitest.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    setupFiles: ['./src/utils/test-utils/setup-tests.ts'],
    css: true
  }
});
```

button-group.tsx:

```
import { ButtonProps } from './';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import styles from './style.css';

// Export required for storybook story
export interface ButtonGroupProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<ButtonProps>[];
}

const ButtonGroup = ({ children }: ButtonGroupProps) => {
  console.log(styles);
  return <div className={styles['button-group']}>{children}</div>;
};

ButtonGroup.displayName = 'ButtonGroup';

ButtonGroup.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node).isRequired
};

export default React.memo(ButtonGroup);
```

button-group.test.tsx:

```
import Button from '../index';
import ButtonGroup from '../button-group';
import { expect } from 'vitest';
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('ButtonGroup Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('renders a button group', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button>Button 2</Button>
        <Button>Button 3</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Button 3' })
      ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
    expect(container.firstChild).toHaveClass('button-group');
    expect(container.firstChild?.childNodes).toHaveLength(3);
  });
});
```

The test fails as the element has an empty string for class, and I'm unsure why. I've also tried explicitly including all css in the config with `css: { include: /.*/ }`, but that didn't work either. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but have been unable to find the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using an alias to resolve css using `identity-obj-proxy`, which what was doing the actual heavy lifting for this in jest as well.

vitest.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    setupFiles: ['./src/utils/test-utils/setup-tests.ts'],
    alias: [
      {
        find: /.*\.(?:css)$/,
        replacement: 'identity-obj-proxy'
      }
    ],
    css: {
      include: /.*/
    },
    globals: true,
    deps: {
      web: {
        transformCss: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```